# Usually, which one to use, transform or stream, places less load on memory?

Tags: java, jpa, memory, transform, querydsl

A question arose while using querydsl.
I heard that using transform can be dangerous because it uses a lot of memory. However, if you don't use transform, you will use memory through something like a stream anyway, so I'm curious what the difference is between the two.
If the differences between the two are similar, wouldn't it be okay to just use transform?

For reference, the number of stores according to the results is about 10,000. Each store has about 3 keywords.

## "When using stream"

```java
   @Override
    public Page<MyLikeStoreResponse> findMyLikeStore(Long memberId, Pageable pageable) {

        List<Store> storeQuery =
                jpaQueryFactory
                        .select(likes.store)
                        .from(likes)
                        .join(likes.store, store)
                        .join(likes.member, member)
                        .leftJoin(store.storeKeywordList, storeKeyword)
                        .leftJoin(storeKeyword.keyword, keyword)
                        .where(member.memberId.eq(memberId))
                        .offset(pageable.getOffset())
                        .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
                        .fetch();

        List<MyLikeStoreResponse> response = createMyLikeStoreResponse(storeQuery);

        int count = jpaQueryFactory
                .select(store)
                .from(likes)
                .join(likes.store, store)
                .join(likes.member, member)
                .where(member.memberId.eq(memberId))
                .fetch()
                .size();


        return new PageImpl<>(response, pageable, count);
    }
   private List<MyLikeStoreResponse> createMyLikeStoreResponse(List<Store> storeQuery){
        return storeQuery
                .stream()
                .map(store ->
                        MyLikeStoreResponse
                                .builder()
                                .phone(store.getPhone())
                                .storeId(store.getStoreId())
                                .address(store.getAddress())
                                .storeName(store.getName())
                                .keywordList(store.getStoreKeywordList().stream()
                                        .limit(3)
                                        .map(storeKeyword -> storeKeyword.getKeyword().getName())
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                .build()
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

### Performance test - stream

Performance test results using visualVM (requests were sent about 10 times): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wymAz.png

## When using transform

```java
@Override
    public Page<MyLikeStoreResponse> findMyLikeStore(Long memberId, Pageable pageable) {

        List<MyLikeStoreResponse> response = jpaQueryFactory
                .select(likes.store)
                .from(likes)
                .join(likes.store, store)
                .join(likes.member, member)
                .leftJoin(store.storeImageList, image).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(store.storeKeywordList, storeKeyword)
                .leftJoin(storeKeyword.keyword, keyword)
                .where(member.memberId.eq(memberId))
                .offset(pageable.getOffset())
                .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
                .transform(groupBy(store.storeId).list(
                        Projections.constructor(
                                MyLikeStoreResponse.class,
                                store.storeId,
                                store.name.as("storeName"),
                                store.address,
                                store.phone,
                                list(storeKeyword.keyword.name).as("keywordList")
                        )
                ));


        int count = jpaQueryFactory
                .select(store)
                .from(likes)
                .join(likes.store, store)
                .join(likes.member, member)
                .where(member.memberId.eq(memberId))
                .fetch()
                .size();


        return new PageImpl<>(response, pageable, count);
    }
```

### Performance test - transform

Performance test results using visualVM (requests were sent about 10 times):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ide5.png

And the stream method is approximately 100ms faster (measured using Postman).

## question

1. Did I conduct the performance test correctly? I think I sent too few requests.
2. There seems to be no difference comparing stream and transform. Is my judgment correct?
3. Is it the right choice to conduct performance testing of both? Can we conclude that the two are similar without testing?
4. Why is stream faster? Is there a reason you are planning to go?